# Burninate the "dynamic" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion, burninate-request

I just edited the [online](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) tag and noted some synonyms for "online" algorithms. Among them are "dynamic" algorithms, so I looked whether we have a [dynamic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) tag or similar and whether making it a synonym for [online](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) would be warranted.

We have four tags containing the word "dynamic": [dynamic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic), [dynamic-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-regression), [linear-dynamical-system](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-dynamical-system) and [dynamic-linear-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-linear-model). From what I can tell, the last three are fine (though the last two could profit from a tag wiki).

However, [dynamic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) is a mess. [It looks like it has been inserted in questions on specific techniques that happen to have "dynamic" in their name, or in other instances that have something "dynamic" about them.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) There is no common overarching theme. I don't, for instance, see a way to write a tag wiki, nor do I believe anyone will ever filter on this unspecific tag.

I propose that [dynamic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) should be deleted and blacklisted, AKA burninated, so it won't be misused in the future. Thoughts?

Comment: +1 but given that not a single tag has ever been burninated on CV so far (despite many good suggestions) and given that [dynamic] has merely 18 threads, it might be an easier solution to eliminate it manually. Blacklisting is usually not necessary: it is unlikely to get recreated soon, given that we have three other tags with the word "dynamic" in them (that will pop up as suggestions when somebody is tagging a question).

Comment: By the way, deleting & blacklisting $\ne$ burninating. Burninating means silent mass-deletion. Blacklisting means deprecating future use.

Comment: Unrelated to the main question, but regarding the [online] tag wiki excerpt. (1) Italics are not displayed in excerpts so `*...*` is only disturbing. (2) Tag links are not displayed in excerpts, so the same goes for `[tag:...]`. (3) I feel the new excerpt is too long and can benefit from some shortening, see http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2848.

Comment: @amoeba: thank you. I wish, I wish info like this were available when editing a tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: I agree with the observations made by @amoeba. The best solution would seem to be (1) create a short wiki excerpt for [tag:dynamic] that explains how it should (not) be used and then (2) manually retag the 18 threads that have been affected.

Comment: @whuber: I'll happily delete the tag, but I don't see how a wiki (excerpt) would ever make sense. There simply is no "overall" use for "dynamic", apart from the three more specific tags. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: The point of the excerpt is to inform people that the tag should not be used and to suggest alternatives.

Comment: I wrote such a wiki excerpt.

Comment: @whuber, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the tag will disappear in 24 hours once it is removed from all threads, so the excerpt won't be seen by anyone / make any difference.

Comment: @gung There are two unknowns.  The first is whether the tag really ought to be removed from all questions.  Even if it is, I do not know whether the excerpt is truly removed from the system: possibly it would reappear the next time somebody tried to tag a thread with "dynamic."

Comment: @whuber After Stephan eliminated the tag and it was removed from the system, I posted a test question with the same "dynamic" tag. The tag wiki excerpt (that I wrote before the tag was eliminated) did *not* reappear. See comments below Stephan's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I have removed all [dynamic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) tags. For good measure, I also changed all [dynamic-linear-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-linear-model) ones to [dynamic-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-regression).

Let's see what happens to the tags. If the tags remain, we can edit the wikis to point to this thread.

(This just so I can accept my own answer so the issue is closed.)

Comment: Starting the protocol. The [tag:dynamic] tag page still exists, shows tag wiki excerpt and zero threads.

Comment: The tag seems to have disappeared now.

Comment: I have posted [a test question with "dynamic" tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223894). The tag wiki excerpt did not come back, see [tag:dynamic] page. I will delete this question after some minutes.

Comment: I erased the test question. The [tag:dynamic] tag page still exists, showing empty tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: (Forgot to check earlier.) The tag is gone again, for good. End of protocol.